# How to upload vector data to OpenStreetMap ( quickly )?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, vector-layer

I have 3 shapefiles containing:

1. 8791 Linestrings
2. 6704 Linestrings
3. 584 Polygons

I want to upload this data to OSM ( share it ) I took a look at the [guidelines](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) of uploading data to OSM. And I want to know how should I structure my data in order to be conform to OSM norms.

So what I'm asking for the structure that I need to get my shapefiles in to be accepted ( attributes, types, ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ahead of yourself, review the Guidelines and make sure you succeeded in **all of the steps**. Before you have gotten discussion on the imports mailing list there should be no thoughts wasted on data wrangling.

The data structure of OSM itself is explained in http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features

You will need to invest considerable amounts of time. OSM is not a place to just dump data in, you would need to make sure that you do not interfere with existing data.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I think that you've almost certainly misunderstood the fundamentals of how Openstreetmap works. I can't imagine it being possible to make the judgement that your data should be uploaded to OSM without already knowing the 'OSM norms' like the back of your hand.

This isn't the place to explain - there are good resources out there already, and a community of contributors who may be enthusiastic about the data you hold if you ask.

Can I recommend help.openstreetmap.org

It may well be that the data you hold is of great value to the Openstreetmap community. Explain on help.openstreetmap.org about what the data is, and if it is useful then contributors will be more than enthusiastic about helping you get it used in one way or another.